# Object instance evocation by provided variable

Tags: python-3.4, pyqt5

imagine there is a set of objects, like:

```
class oven():
    pass
class delta_t_pause():
    pass
class caliberBox():
    pass
class caliberRectl():
    pass
class caliberRound():
    pass
```

and so on. There is a `class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton)` which receives two variables when evoked by mouse click. On variable carries an id the other data to be stored in the object.

What I want to do is, create an instance of the object matching the id. Assigning the data to it might be done by obj = Object(data), which is no big deal.

Does anyone has some useful ideas how to achieve that? I'm kinda stuck here.

```
class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, senderid, items, parent):
        super().__init__(senderid, items, parent)
        print(senderid)
        self.obj = items

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        QtWidgets.QPushButton.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print(event.button(),' pressed')
```

is what I have so far...

Something like
    if senderid is in list:
        obj = Object(data)
but how do I select the right Object

All programming is done in Python-3.4 and PyQt5.5.

cheers,
Christian

Comment: How is the button supposed to "receive" variables when clicked? Receive from where?

Comment: That's done by a method of the main window. The reception's made by the __init__ line of the Button class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a dictionary that maps ids to classes. Then you can use the dict to create your object.

```
objects = {4: oven, 8: delta_t_pause, 15: caliberBox}
if senderid in objects:
    obj = objects[senderid](data)
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I was a little bit puzzled about using the dict to create the objects. But it looks like what I wanted. Thx.